# How many milliseconds interval does angularjs re-render the ui?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

as title shown.

when we bind somethings like

```
$scope.text="ASD";
```

in html:

```
this is {{text}}
```

and when we change $scope.text, in html the value also changed, because of the 2 way binding.

my question is how many milliseconds does angularjs update the ui?

**EDITED:**

Sorry, i think my question not details enough and i also quite confuse how to perfect define my question. 
the extra question is,

there is a $http, after successful get the data,
assgin to some variable, called $scope.list. and this list is bind to ui ngRepeat. So when i get the data, i am **not** directly assign like this

```
$scope.list = data;
```

because it will re-render the ngRepeat DOM, instead of that, i am manually assign the data

```
pseudo-code 
for loop scope list
  for loop data
    if object equal then assing value to scope list [index] = data[index]
  end loop
end loop
```

here is the example http://plnkr.co/edit/IHt6AoVUhRsUlBuumEGr?p=preview why i manually set instead of using **"="**

so back to the question, when i doing update list and i also add up time condition, for example in the loop

```
pseudo-code 
for loop scope list
  for loop data
    every 0.001 secs do somethings, and manual set the value to the list
  end loop
end loop
```

So in the inner loop and at that time of assign value , the UI update is it trigger by the event or by a certain time?

Comment: To avoid the rerender, use "track by" in ng-repeat.  For instance, if your objects have an id, ng-repeat="obj in list track by obj.id".  Ng-repeat will handle the checking for you and only replace or remove new or deleted items.

Comment: i don know using track by can avoid rerender the ui. LOL . Well, but in the inner loop, i manage to change the value, so at that time the ui rerender is it by event trigger or in time? or any references for me to study?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the UI won't update until after the loop is finished.  I'm going to regret this next sentence....you could implement the inner loop using $timeout, in which case the DOM would be rendered after each element was changed, but why you would do this I have no idea.

Comment: This is because i want do somethings like , example: 0 to 5, increase from 0 to 5 in 1 seconds, so the interval will be 0.2s and increase 1 per interval. then another 1 is 0 to 100 in 1 seconds, the interval will be 0.01s and also increase 1 per interval. thats why i need to figure out all those things to develop my things. i will go for more test $timeout later.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** none, but you may feel like it is taking a few milliseconds depending on your processor speed and the amount of things angular need to check before it updates the HTML

**Long answer:** As soon as you update the model (well, at the end of the current javascript context), Angular will execute a digest cycle on which it will process all the $watchers (in this case `{{text}}` is a watcher over the `text` property). If a watcher has a different value than last time, it will run a new digest cycle, and so on, until all watchers are stable. Then it will process the HTML and updates all value, before the browser finally render the view. Hence from a "machine" point of view, it is immediate as in the same execution context: your browser will not render anything in between.

Now if your code is asynchronous (like a call to some server), that "immediaticity" I have been talking about starts from the latest call to `$scope.$apply`

Comment: You're probably doing it wrong and not asking the right question (see XY problem), instead you should give us a bigger bicture of what exactly you're trying to do so we can help you. Anyway, here is a plunker with the use of $timeout: http://plnkr.co/edit/g4kI9CnMtNMys07Oi3ek?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS updates the UI on every [`$digest`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) cycle. `$digest` does not run on a fixed millisecond interval; instead it is run when certain events are triggered in the UI (e.g. changing the text in a text box with an `ng-model` directive).

As @Joe pointed out, if you are running code in an event that Angular knows about (such as an `ng-change` event), then the UI will be updated almost immediately.

If you are running some code that runs at a time that AngularJS is not expecting (e.g. using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, you can force a `$digest` cycle to happen manually by calling `scope.$apply()`, assuming you have a reference to an Angular scope.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $scope.text="ASD" is executed within a digest cycle, the ui will be updated almost immediately.

You can think of the thread of execution to be:

```
$scope.text="ASD"
...other code in this digest cycle (most likely nothing)
...renderui()
```

In terms of milliseconds, I guess that depends on how fast your CPU is.

Another way to say this is that it's going to be just as fast as if you manually updated the DOM yourself, with a small amount of overhead included for running angular's digest cycle.